# Can an estate be forced to sell real estate to cover debt if the home was bequeathed to an adult child?

Tags: debt, probate, west-virginia

My mother died in West Virginia.  I am her son and the executor of her will, in which the home was bequeathed to me. The estate has insufficient funds to pay medical and other debts. Can WV probate court force me to sell the home to pay the medical and other debts? Can liens be placed on the home prior to, or after probate closes (and the home, I presume, will become mine)?

Comment: Not being familiar with WV law, and mindful of your awful situation, I think it would be a good idea to get professional legal assistance to sort this out for you. It will cost money but is also likely to prevent costly mistakes.

Comment: I don't know if it makes a difference in your jurisiction, but was the home you place of residence before the death?

Comment: @JCRM: No. I live several states away.

Comment: You may have thought of this, but if your mother had a lawyer who helped her write her will, that lawyer may be willing to talk to you. If you don't already have one, the firm may also have a packet with forms and lists of things to do.

Comment: @Just a guy: unfortunately, my parents did one of those online wills. That alone was a headache to get the court to accept--had to get a lawyer involved to make that happen. So a word of caution to anyone reading that may be relying on such a will---at least take such a prepared will to a lawyer to confirm there are no issues with it.

Comment: @peinal Dang! You just can't catch a break, can you? Having been there and done that, **I second your advice.** It's amazing how much headache what look like little changes/mistakes can cause.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I am sorry for your loss, and that you have to deal with bills on top of everything else.

The quick answer is yes, you might have to sell the house to pay your mother's bills.

As you probably know, the estate includes both your mother's assets (cash, house, car, and so on) and her debts. In general, to "settle the estate," the executor must pay all debts before she gives away any of the assets.

*Legal Aid of West Virginia* has a [helpful website](https://www.lawv.net/Resources/Self-Help-Library/Individual-Rights/Probate-The-process-for-Dealing-with-Property-and-Debts-after-Death) about West Virginia probate law. Here is what it says about this issue:

> If you can’t pay all of your family member’s creditors from the person’s available money, you must sell off the family member’s property and pay the creditors in the order listed in W. Va. Code § 44-2-21; W. Va. Code §§ 44-1-18 to -20. **You may have to sell the family member’s land or home in order to pay creditors.** W. Va. Code § 44-8-7.

**Added after comments**

Under WV law, it does not matter that you were bequeathed your mother’s house. The law gives debtors priority over heirs. This means debtors are paid before any heir. Heirs are “paid” from *whatever is left* in the estate *after* the debts are paid. So if the estate is underwater, if it owes more than it is worth, there will be nothing left in the estate to give to the heirs.

As executor, your job is to carry out West Virginia law.

The nuts and bolts of what happens if you refuse to the sell the house depends on WV law. You might be able to find the details by searching on line, but your best bet is to probably to talk to an attorney who specializes in WV  probate law. An attorney will know both the law on the books, and how that law is implemented. They will be able to advise you on what options you really have, and the costs and benefits of those options.

If the estate is underwater, you could buy the house from the estate. If you do that, you will not be liable for any of your mother’s debts; those are owed by the estate. Depending on how the sale is handled, this may be your (financially) best option.

(Depending on whether the price covers the debt, and on what other heirs are bequeathed, the court might worry about you selling yourself the house at a discount price, and thus look at the sale very carefully.)

Comment: Thanks for the condolences.  Perhaps I worded my question poorly. I mean, more specifically, can a probate judge ORDER the home be sold  when the home was bequeathed to me? If so, who/how is sale price set? and what if it does not sell? and what time frame would it have to sell within? What if I want to keep it as a future retirement home? Am I out-of-luck?  or do I then inherit the debts? (The house was paid for). I don't think I have to worry on the Medicaid front-- they did not get Medicaid.

Comment: @peinal Quick answer: yes, they can order it sold. You worded your question fine, but since I obviously didn't give you a complete answer, let me go back and edit it in response to your comments. PS You are welcome. I've had to do this a few times, so I know how confusing it can be. After our mother died, my brother said that if we wrote an idiot's guide to estate settlement, we'd help millions and make millions.

Comment: Well its actually much worse that 1st appearances. My father murdered her then committed suicide-- so I have two probate processes to go thru.

Comment: @peinal Oh, no! I can't imagine.

Comment: I assume they cannot order the home to be sold if the person supposed to inherit it pays the money owned.

Comment: @gnasher729-- of course that makes sense; but, in this case the beneficiary cannot afford to pay the monies owed.

Comment: Would the court care if the house was sold at a discounted price if it was still sufficient to pay off all creditors and didn't disenfranchise any other potential heirs?

Comment: @Bobson Good question. It sounds as if the court won't care in this instance. In general, whether they care depends on what other bequests were made in the will. For instance, suppose another heir had been *specifically* bequeathed something else that was sold to satisfy debts. That heir would be entitled to a share of the proceeds from the sale of the house.  **I rewrote that sentence. Please let me know if it's still unclear. **

Comment: @Justaguy - Thanks.  Good to know, and much clearer now.

Comment: @Bobson You are welcome. And thanks for pointing out the problem. I'm not always good about spotting my own mistakes (other people's mistakes, however, seem to jump off the page!).

Comment: @Bobson I guess the sale of the house would have to pay whatever sales tax applies, and the organism that collects those may object if the price is too low as it would lower the amount of taxes to pay. OTOH, then the buyer no longer would have to pay inheritance tax on the house, but only on whatever cash remains after paying debtors.

Comment: And I guess there is no need for the money to actually exchange hands between the OP and himself, making the operations virtual "I have $100K and the value of the house is $250K, I buy the house for $250K, pay $100K to debtors, pay the sales tax of the $250K value and inheritance for the $150K that remains from selling the house." The OP could accept an IOU from himself. But unless there is a reason for it (other heirs), it seems that the OP paying the debtors directly would be easier and cheaper.

Comment: I normally hate the "Lawyer Up" response, but when you're dealing with probate, having an attorney to deal with the process is a blessing. They get paid from the estate, so you don't need to pay out-of-pocket. And it will go a long way toward shielding you from any accusations of impropriety, both formally (through the court) and otherwise (Aunt Helen thinks you stole her inheritance). Just make sure everyone understands that this is not "your lawyer" being used as a weapon against them, but is instead the lawyer of the estate.

Answer (score 16):

You have to pay the debts from the assets that comprise the estate, to the extent that it is possible, but the executor has some discretion in how that happens. [This law](http://www.wvlegislature.gov/wvcode/ChapterEntire.cfm?chap=44&art=2&section=21#02) determines what order debts are to be paid in: funeral expenses are high on the list, last-illness debts are lower but still ahead of "everything else". [§44-1-17 though -21](http://www.wvlegislature.gov/wvcode/Code.cfm?chap=44&art=1#01) cover assets to be sold or not sold, but except for the family food and fuel exemption, anything can be sold, and debts must be paid. There will not be any debts of the estate after the estate is closed, more or less [by definition](http://www.wvlegislature.gov/wvcode/ChapterEntire.cfm?chap=44&art=4&section=14A#04). There is a Final Settlement form where you say what was in the estate and what claims there were, and how the property was disbursed and the claims satisfied. If there are still debts, you have to pay those debts and can't e.g. sell the house and divide the procedes without paying those debts. (By "can't", I mean that as executor you get in legal trouble).

You will know what those debts are because creditors have [60 days to file a claim](http://www.wvlegislature.gov/wvcode/ChapterEntire.cfm?chap=44&art=1&section=14A#01). You have to publish a notice, in a form prescribed by law, that basically says "X died, send your claims here" (read the statute to get it right). If somebody comes along a year later and demands payment, they are out of luck.

A creditor can't just "put a lien on a house", although a contractor who did work on the house could put a mechanic's lien on the house if they were not paid for their work. The IRS can put a lien on your house for non-payment of taxes. But if a bank lends someone money to run a business and they don't pay off the loan—unless the loan was secured with the property as collateral—they can't just put a lien on the house. Nevertheless, as executor, you have to pay that debt at least to the extent that there is any property at all in the estate.

Comment: Can an executor refuce to keep acting as the executor when they discover the level of debts?

Comment: @IanRingrose I don't see why discovering that would change anything about if they could or couldn't decline to be executor.  The key phrase here is "to the extent possible", which means if someone died with $20k in assets and $100k in debt, the executors job would be to sell the assets, pay off $20k in debt, and inform the holders of the other $80k that they're not getting their money back ever.  That's probably a bit over simplified, since the law specifies (at least in part, secured vs unsecured debt if nothing else) how the partial repayments are distributed.

Comment: As executor, you're not personally responsible for the remainder of the debt if the estates assets can't cover it all.

Comment: You can shirk your responsibilities for whatever reason you want and under §44-1-9 the court may appoint an appropriate person to finish the job. Personal liability isn't an issue if you act in good faith

Comment: @DanIsFiddlingByFirelight most executor only do the unpaid work before them or someone they care about benfits from the will.

Comment: @DanIsFiddlingByFirelight Go look at the link. It says the debits in a given class need to be paid 'pro rata' with no preference. So in your example if one debit is for 20k and the other 80k, then the first should get 4k and the other 16k.

Answer (score 12):

### Yes, in theory, but pursue other options too

Yes, in theory, the estate would have to liquidate property to cover those debts.  In theory.

First, it doesn't necessarily need to be *the house*.   If other assets are saleable, that will suffice.

Second, the estate does not necessarily need to *sell* the house.  It could, for instance, **mortgage** the house to obtain cash to settle the debts.  Who would write such a mortgage?  Someone friendly - a family member - maybe even the person to whom the house is bequeathed.  It also may be possible to structure a deal with a commercial mortgage wherein the estate takes the mortgage (with you as co-party) and then you take possession of the house with assent of the mortgage writer.  Now you own a house, albeit with a mortgage.

### Haggle those debts mercilessly - especially medical debt.

Many firms, especially those who function in the elder-care/end of life business, "know the drill".  For instance my grandparents both got medicines from a company which is a darling of nursing homes.  *So most of their business is geriatric*.  When my grandmother passed, they cheerfully settled her outstanding invoice for half, without even putting up a fight - the estate was fully attachable, they didn't even try.  When her husband passed, they just walked away and settled for $0. This is old-hat for them.

Many other medical bills are insanely "puffed up" for business reasons.  Hospitals' bread-and-butter business is in-network insurance work, where they are locked down by contract to "Reasonable, Usual & Customary" industry rates, such as $47 for a blood test series or $70 for a COVID-19 test.  However, when dealing out-of-network or with the uninsured, the prices suddenly puff up to $320 (happened to me) for a blood test or $2,315 for a COVID-19 test. **The hospitals have no realistic expectation that a cash patient will pay this**.

They do it a) to profiteer off medical tourism (wealthy people in the third world think America has a wonderful healthcare system; and they can and do pay those crazy numbers). Many people who can pay won't put up a fight, and it's easy money - like taking candy from babies.  (think about that before you scream "morals").  For those who do fight, it gives them a ridiculously highball number to start with; "I'll knock it down from $2315 to $1000 if you pay today for that $70 COVID test".  (again, anyone care to argue a moral duty to pay $2315?)  For the vast majority of customers who can never pay, it allows the hospital to puff up their paper losses for fundraising reasons.  "We donated $1.2 billion of services to those who couldn't pay" *(read: after we burned their credit rating to the ground trying to collect)*.

All of that to say, you must look at those medical bills *not at all like a real number*, but as an absurd highball number from which you start negotiating.   But you have to handle that creditor by creditor: I saw $105 bills for a doctor's visit with an independent doctor; that guy was clearly not profiteering, so I paid that in full).

### And you can haggle down any creditor, and be ruthless!

The creditor cannot *simply attach a lein* on the estate; they have to go through a huge rigmarole of dunning, filing suit, battling with your lawyer... **they know perfectly well that** if you dig in your heels, they will probably spend $5000 and possibly $10,000 *just getting to a judge's verdict*, and that only allows them to start another long road: the collections process, and they have to grind through all of that (possibly another $5000) to finally attach that lein on the house.

So figure that into your offers: if the estate owes a credit card $7000, offer to settle the debt for $500.  It's lowball, but you may both find a happy number in the $1000-3000 range.  *Creditors do this all the time*.

A hospital could take their outlandish bill down 75% or more if you are extremely persistent.

**To be clear: They cannot sue you or attach debt to you, in any way whatsoever**. So they can scream and howl all they want; they cannot do anything **to you**; they can only target *the estate*.  And that's a long, long road to payback, for them.  Never assent to take on the estate's debt personally - that's just suicide.

- Well, there might be a case for personally accepting some estate debt as part of a plan to eliminate all the estate's debt and leave you in a good position, but that is so complex and dangerous you must only do it on advice of your lawyer who is fully in the loop. The asset protection questions are too complex - will this house be homesteaded, will you be converting secured debt to unsecured, etc. You need a pro.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can surrender your duties as executor to the state. However you can forget about anything that may have come to you after debts are paid, as the state's lawyers expenses will eat up everything.
It might be worth it, however, just to be rid of the mental stress, the huge amounts of time and paperwork, and the risk of getting something wrong and getting sued by somebody. It took me two years each to settle/ probate two different relatives estates and they were relatively simple.  What a grind.

Comment: I never considered surrender of my appointment-- didn't know it was an option. The will named an alternate person to serve, but I have little faith that this person has the nerves or intelligence that it would require. (not disparaging him--but he has no post-secondary education or experience with financial matters). Simply stated, I believe I can do a better job--despite my lack of any formal legal knowledge. 6 more wks & I will have a better picture of what the estate is facing regarding claims. More than likely, I will hire a lawyer to represent the estate if things look too harrowing.

Comment: Why on earth would someone do that?  Oh right, mental stress... well better to pass it off to another trusted family member, or hire your own team, including your own lawyer on your own terms, and a (much less expensive) accountant.  Those terms could include remaining executor but consulting with the lawyer on anything really hard, so the fees wouldn't be bad.   In fact the  team is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest case would be that you used all the cash and sold all valuables to pay for debts, and now the remaining estate is $10,000 debt and a $200,000 home that you are supposed to inherit.

You can clearly satisfy the debt, therefore you have to. The possibilities are: You convince someone (maybe yourself) to pay the debt, and you keep the home. Or you sell the home, try hard to get the best price, pay the debt and keep the rest. If you refuse, the creditors will go to court, which forces you to sell the home or sells it itself, not trying very hard to get a good price. So forcing you to sell is possible, but would be the courts last choice.